# Using sql variable and add more into it

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to add sql code to an existing variable that also contains sql code.

```
$strSQLSel = $strSQLSel + "GROUP BY historyTransactions.entityid
                           ORDER BY historyTransactions.entityid";
```

I get this error:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 102
>   [code] => 102 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Incorrect syntax near '0'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
>   11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '0'. ) )

Comment: The first statement has a missing double quote.

Comment: ...and $sql has a missing whitespace between tablename and `WHERE`.

Comment: What is a whitespace? @IvanStarostin

Comment: `Customers WHERE` "space". right now you have `CustomersWHERE` which is an unknown construction/keyword.

Answer (score 0):

The first statement has a missing `double` `quote`. You should also use parameters instead of directly injecting variables. This way you could protect your database from [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

See : https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2981/using-parameters-for-sql-server-queries-and-stored-procedures/